# How to include a picture as a binary MIME attachment - POST request Ebay API? (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mime

Hi guys I hope someone can help me with this as Ive been trying for 6hrs!

The Ebay Docs say: *"Include the picture as a binary MIME attachment, sent after the XML input in the same POST request"* http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/UploadSiteHostedPictures.html

In my code I am using 'NSMutableURLRequest', setting the headers:

```
 NSString *requestEncoding = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"801"];
[request addValue:requestEncoding forHTTPHeaderField: @"X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL"];
```

... etc. Then I am setting the body; of which setting a picture URL is part of it:

```
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<PictureURL>%@</PictureURL></PictureDetails>", self.fullURLForEbayHostedPic]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

If I pass in a URL of an image stored somewhere on another server, this works fine. However: I have no idea how to pass a file stored on the device up to the Ebay server.

From my interpretation of the Ebay docs, I need to add the binary data to the end of the XML (the very last thing) whilst giving the above 'PictureURL' reference to it; though Im totally stuck at that.

I did find this C# example: https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1093 and tried to fit in some of the elements from that (modified for objective-c counterparts), but to no avail.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Carl.

Comment: If anyone is interested: I got round this by uploading my image to another server (in this case www.parse.com) and then transfered straight away to the Ebay server. Feels a bit cheeky doing is this way but it works well ;)

Comment: oh.. and if anyone still wants to answer this is be grateful, as im sure I will come up against the same issue again (in another context)

Comment: were you ever able to figure this one out? I have same problem

Comment: Hi Bryan... could you share please? I revisited this the other day and still could not find out how to do it. Thanks, Carl.

Comment: are you using curl? I did it in c++ but I dont think it will be much different. Post your code (without ebay token codes of course) Ill point out where it may be bugging out.

Comment: I could use Curl to test... though at the moment its just running in my app. The code is pretty much what I have above; though obviously there are more headers /  XML. Did you attach your pic at the end of your XML feed as binary data?